# Scheduling a pentaho job in SQL server agent

Tags: pentaho, sql-server-agent

I have built out a simple FTP job in Pentaho that places a file in a local directory. I need to be able to call this job in a SQL server agent job which I can then schedule and use, but when I set the agent job up it runs through the steps successfully but does not produce anything to show that it was in fact successful.

I am pretty confident the Pentaho job itself is fine because it can be run through the UI, command line, and .bat file. Everything works as expected except when I try to make this SQL Server Agent job and I have no idea why!

[Here is the only step in the job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrmXT.jpg) When I use this i'm prompted with no errors but nothing actually happens. If I try to enclose it in quotes I get an error.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Since you specify C: in your `cd` command you should use 'cd /d'. What happens if you put this in a .bat file and just run it from the cmd line?

Comment: It worked in every instance except for the SQL Server Agent job. Figured it out though and posted the answer below. Thanks though

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out!

Apparently, only the first line of the command was executing. So it was navigating to a different directory but not executing any commands. I remedied this by putting everything on one line and adding a && to it.

Command line used: cd c:\pentaho\data-integration && kitchen.bat /file:C:\pentaho\Jobs\BW\FTP_BW_TRN.kjb /level:Basic